# Redirect Subdomain To another subfolder same structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to know how to redirect subdomain to another subfolder with same structure by .htaccess

for example i want to redirect

```
bookmarks.site.com
```

to

```
www.site.com/bookmarks
```

and if someone go to link

```
http://bookmarks.site.com/story.php?title=free-logo-design
```

it will redirect it to

```
http://www.site.com/bookmarks/story.php?title=free-logo-design
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```